# Why this factor $1/r$ is used in the equation of asymptotic behavior of scattered wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, time-evolution, scattering-cross-section

Why $1/r$ factor is used?
And in this equation $f_k(\theta,\varphi)$ is scattering amplitude then why plane wave ($e^{ikz}$) amplitude is not used?

[image]

Comment: Please use LaTeX to include equations in your post rather than posting images of them.

Comment: Because without that factor, the wavefunction won't satisfy scattering Hamiltonian for r trending to infinity

Comment: But how?  Can u please explain? @aneetkumar

Answer (score 0):

For large r, the scattering Hamiltonian reduced to the one of a free particle. This wavefunction which is limiting expression of wavefunction for $r\rightarrow \infty$, should satisfy the free particle Hamiltonian. Putting $1/r$ serves the purpose.

Verify it yourself-put this expression in the Hamiltonian of a free particle with momentum $\hbar k$ and see whether the equation is satisfied.